# Javascript: How do I open url links automatically that are linkedin?

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink

I've tried many methods, but they all seem to fail. I got so mad I removed my script out of frustration. Any tips on how to open url links that are associated with linkedin in a new window. As you can tell, I am a new when it comes to Javascript.

I know how to open a separate window, but not one associated with linkedin url.

```
 window.open($("a:contains('http')").text(), "", "_blank");
```

Comment: `How do I open url links automatically that are linkedin?` so you mean if you page has 10 anchor tags with 8 of them being linkedin you want to open 8 tabs automatically?

Comment: Sort of. I need to open it in a separate window not a tab. However, you have the right idea.

Comment: JQuery's  "text" method returns the text inside the element, so you might have a link <a href='linkedin.html'>Click here</a> and your code will return "Click here".  If you want it to return "linkedin.html", read the href attribute instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample code which will take all the `anchor` tag in the body and if the `href` contains `linkedin.com` it will open it in new tab.

```
$.each($('body a'),function(){
 if($(this).attr('href').indexof('linkedin.com') > -1){
   window.open($(this).attr('href'), "", "_blank");
 }
});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS solution

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href*=\"linkedin.com\"]"), function(anchor) {
   window.open(anchor.href, "_blank");
});
```